# Featured Video replacing Featured Image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am trying to create a list of an "animation" post category, where each of these posts **has a video associated with it**. I want the video to be accessible inside the post itself, of course, but I also want to create a list/grid of these animations in an "Animations" page. I want the "featured image" or "thumbnail" of each of these posts to be the animation itself, **so the user can start watching the video without clicking into the post**.

Now there are plugins that do something like that using a bit of duct tape. But I want the video to **actually replace** the featured image so third-party plugins like Elementor will see the "featured video" when they try to insert the thumbnail in some sort of content block, so the image is actually replaced by the video everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not have its own function for this yet.

You can do this with a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Featured+Video/

Comment: Searching "Featured Video" in the plugin store was my first course of action.

Kindly read the second paragraph of my question.